# fsc.exe is very slow because it tries to access crl.microsoft.com

Tags: networking, f#

When I run F# compiler - fsc.exe - on our build server it takes ages (~20sec) to run even when there are no input files. After some investigation I found out that it's because the application tries to access crl.microsoft.com (probably to check if some certificates aren't revoked). However, the account under which it runs doesn't have an access to the Internet. And because our routers/firewalls/whatever just drops the SYN packets, fsc.exe tries several times before giving up.

The only solution which comes to mind is to set clr.microsoft.com to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file but it's pretty nasty solution. Moreover, I'll need fsc.exe on our production box, where I can't do such things. Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Come across this myself - here are some links... to better descriptions and some alternatives

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29381925/code-signing-performance-problems-with-certificate-revocation-chec.aspx

I dug up this form an old MS KB for Exchange when we hit it...  Just got the DNS Server to reply as stated (*might be the solution for your production box.*)

[MS Support KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944752)

> The CRL check is timing out because it
>   never receives a response. If a router
>   were to send a “no route to host” ICMP
>   packet or similar error instead of
>   just dropping the packets, the CRL
>   check would fail right away, and the
>   service would start. You can add an
>   entry to crl.microsoft.com in the
>   hosts file or on the DNS server and
>   send the packets to a legitimate
>   location on the network, such as
>   127.0.0.1, which will reject the connection..."

Comment: The last link helped. I added fsc.exe.config as advised there and it did the trick. Still quite crappy solution, but best so far. Thanks