# F# is running very slow since last round of Windows updates

Tags: f#

I recently installed the latest rounds of Windows updates, including the .NET 4.0 updates and the Visual Studio updates (but not VS2010 SP1).  Since then, my F# compiler has been running really, really slow.  I thought it might be this problem with [crl.microsoft.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514059/fsc-exe-is-very-slow-because-it-tries-to-access-crl-microsoft-com), but it turns out not to be.  Also, I think mscorsvw.exe has completed running.  (I forget the command to force it, but it doesn't kick in, even when the machine is idle.)

Also:

The F# compiler is producing correctly running code, just slowly.

The C# compiler remains as fast as always.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

-Neil

Answer (score 8):

I forgot to run [ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx).  After running that, F# compiles are back to normal speed.

-Neil

Comment: Will `ngen.exe executeQueuedItems` do the trick, or do you have to specify targets?

Comment: I just did ngen.exe executeQueuedItems. I don't know whether that's the *best* way, but it's what I learned years ago from this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/04/27/412838.aspx Keep in mind that it can run for a long time.